# ATK4 - autocomplete display field

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, autocomplete, atk4

Okay, so I'm laying face down on the pavement looking up at the ATK4 learning curve...

I'm trying to set up a simple page much like the Agile demo here: http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/autocomplete using my own db tables.

So, the problem I have is that the database record primary key 'id' is showing up in the autocomplete box. Data all shows properly, but, obviously, I want the complex name (complex_name) column data to show, not the id. I see nowhere to define which column to display, and it appears that agile is deciding that? Can I set it? What am I doing wrong?

Something so simple, but I've been banging my head with no clue how to set this in ATK4 for so many hours now that I could tear my hair out. I have searched and looked at code examples.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class page_index extends Page {
    function init(){

        parent::init();
        $page=$this;

        $form=$this->add('Form');

        $name=$form->addField('autocomplete','complex_name','Complex Lookup/Add')->setModel('Complex');
        $form->getElement('complex_name')->js('change',$form->js()->submit());

        $form2=$this->add('MVCForm');
        $model = $form2->setModel('Complex');
        if($_GET['id'])$model->loadData($_GET['id']);
        $form2->addSubmit();
        if($form2->isSubmitted()){
            $form2->update();
            $form2->js()->reload()->execute();
        }

        if($form->isSubmitted()){
            $form2->js()->reload(array('id'=>$form->get('complex_name')))->execute();
        }
    }
}

<?php
class Model_Complex extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='condo_complexes';
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('complex_name');
        $this->addField('complex_address1');
        $this->addField('complex_city');
        $this->addField('complex_zip');

    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is anyone out there willing to point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: I have simplified the code (edited above), and still no joy. I have spent hours trying to figure this out. I see nothing wrong going from examples - is there anyone willing to look at this for a second and help me?

Comment: I'll post the solution soon. Please use some workaround for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this add-on: https://github.com/atk4/autocomplete

It's not fully finished, but it's in development stage.

Maybe you'll also be interested to follow ATK4 hangouts.
Visit ATK4 homepage and get more info.